# Stopping Windows Error Reporting Manager from uploading

Tags: windows, windows-10

Does anyone know how to stop Windows Error Reporting Manager (wermgr) from constantly uploading on Windows 10 Home? It's clogging up my upload link, which isn't very fast to begin with. It's been uploading for 30mins and still won't stop.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Start->Settings->Privacy->Feedback & diagnostics` and set `Diagnostic and usage data` to `Basic`, to minimize the amount of Diagnostic and usage data sent to Microsoft.

I am not certain that this feature is available on Windows 10 Home but you can try.